# Unable to get Post value from Input File image type

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

i'm not getting any data from input file after submitting the form but other inputs were able to be inserted into db when i removed try and catch statement..what am i doing wrong here..

```
$author = $_SESSION['name'];
$product_image =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name']));
$imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name']);

try
    {
    $mysqli->begin_Transaction();

    $insert_image = $mysqli->query
    (" 
        INSERT INTO product_image
        (
            author,
            regist_date,
            fileType,
            imageData
        )
        VALUES
        (
            '{$author}',
            now(),
            '{$imageProperties['mime']}',
            '{$product_image}'
        )"
    );


    $mysqli->commit();

}

catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $mysqli->rollback();
}
```

and my form

```
<form role="form" id="upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
  <input name="product_image" type="file" class="inputFile" required >`
....
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try to debug and see if the file was properly uploaded? Are you by any chance exceeding MAX_FILE_SIZE or POST_MAX_SIZE?

Comment: Don't put images into the database, that's not where they belong. Plus, do the most basic of debugging, which is a var_dump output of the complete $_FILES array in such a case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in theory your code is valide if you want to submit data to this same php page . but try to do this with adding action attribute to your form

```
<form role="form" id="upload_form" action="PageNameHere.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```